# C# Keep threads alive until event occurs

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, thread-sleep

How can I keep a thread alive until certain events happen? I have a client thread that's waiting for a message from the server that will raise an event on the client(I cannot change this behavior). There are multiple such clients waiting for the MessageReceived event. There should be as little latency as possible so putting the threads to sleep for some amount of time is not a good option.

Currently the only option I've come up with is to keep the thread busy in a while loop so that they are active when the event fires. Is there any better option?

Comment: Events aren't tied to threads (unless you have a message loop, in which case you don't have a problem).  Or are you just asking for `AutoResetEvent`?

Comment: Have you looked into Event Wait Handles? http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles

Answer (score 3):

Use a `ManualResetEvent`. You can create this object, and then use `WaitOne()` and then from another thread, call `Set()` to release the previous blocking call.

Example:

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent();

public void OnOneThread()
{
    //Block here until "OnAnotherThread" is done
    mre.WaitOne();
}

public void OnAnotherThread()
{
    DoWork();
    //Release the other thread
    mre.Set();
}
```

Comment: I can't think of a way to apply this to my question though. Who would be setting the event? I wouldn't want the main thread to also be listening for MessageReceived event on all the clients and then set their individual ManualResetEvent.

Comment: Well if you want an example that fits in your code, you need to put code first :)

Comment: @regal: If the event is firing on the client, then you can have the event handler call the `ManualResetEvent.Set()` method. If the event is firing on the server... then that's another issue entirely.

Comment: Would the event handler even be called though? After all, the thread is blocked by ManualResetEvent

Comment: Only one way to tell, eh? I have no way of telling you what thread fires off your events - most likely it's on a different thread, which will accomplish what you want here.

Comment: The events are invoked on the server and handled by the client. I think it's on the same thread because I connect to the server and start my client in the same thread.

Comment: @regal: We're going to need some code samples, then.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how much it would help,
What I did to deal with multithreading in an exercise I once had,
It was more of a solution to sync between threads, but I guess it can also fit.
I used a mutex, and In the function called by the thread I added a WaitOne() (I think it's called that way),
and once I wanted the thread to go, I unlocked the mutex.
You can do the same, and maybe when the event is raised, unlock the mutex lock.

Edit: What the answer above me says is true. Mixed things above, it IS a ManualResetEvent not a mutex.

But you can use the method I wrote too, just switch mutex with ManualResetEvent.